# Stripe Documentation tells me to expose three APIs on my back end but not how to do so

Tags: ios, api, stripe-payments

In viewing the documentation for incorporating Stripe into my Swift iOS app I read that it tells me: "you should expose three APIs on your backend for your iOS app to communicate with."

The three APIs it is referring to are the retrieve customer API, the create card API and the customer update API. The documentation then lists code snippets for what you should do in your back end to call these APIs, done using the Spark framework, which I am not familiar with.

My question, which Stripe's documentation appears to not explain, is how do I expose my back end to these three APIs so that I may call these functions? Is it through an import statement? OR is this handled/unnecessary by the fact that I would be using the Spark framework which does not require importing?

Link to relevant Stripe documentation: https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Spark framework is the framework that was chosen for the Java example; right above the code areas are some tabs that link to snippets in other languages (Ruby/Sinatra, Python/django, PHP, Node.js/Express), so maybe your language/framework is there - or are you using a different Java framework?

As to your question, you would need to implement those three API endpoints on your server side application - each of which then contact the Stripe API - in order to allow your iOS app to use them.

You might also want to check out Stripe's Java library: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-java/

Comment: My back end is done in Java on AWS Lambda. I just have never used the Spark framework so see it used here was a bit confusing to me. Do you happen to know any resources/info on how to implement the three api endpoints on my server side in a AWS lambda back end?

Comment: Honestly, I've never used AWS lambda - though I'd like to play with it - but as I understand it, these endpoints would each be a separate lambda function that handles one of the three request types.  Not sure if that actually clears it up for you or not. :)

Added a link to the answer as well, referencing the Stripe Java library.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to learn how to do this you should do it in Javascript / Node.JS and use something like Heroku to setup an Express Server.

On the iOS side I would use [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) which will allow you to easily make API calls from your Swift App. The implementation of which would look something like this (For creating a new customer):

```
let apiURL = "https://YourDomain.com/add-customer"
let params = ["email": "hello@test.com"]
let heads = ["Accept": "application/json"]

Alamofire.request(.POST, apiURL, parameters: params, headers: heads)
     .responseJSON { response in
         print(response.request)  // original URL request
         print(response.response) // URL response
         print(response.data)     // server data
         print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

         if let JSON = response.result.value {
             print("JSON: \(JSON)")
         }
     }
```

On the server side, assuming you are using Express have something like this:

```
    app.post('/add-customer', function (req, res) {
    stripe.customers.create(
        { email: req.body.email },
        function(err, customer) {
            err; // null if no error occured
            customer; // the created customer object

            res.json(customer) // Send newly created customer back to client (Swift App)
        }
    );
});
```

Hope this is of some help.